# Can I rerun the failed tests per test case-wise in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying that if any test case from my test-suite is failing, robot should retry n number of times before continuing to next test case. 
I am aware that I can rerun all failed from test-suite using --rerunfailed, but is there any way to rerun individual test before running next one?

Example

```
** Test Cases

 Test 1
     [Documentation] ..
     [Tags]  1
     ..
     ..

 Test 2
     [Documentation] ..
     [Tags]  2
     ..
     ..

 Test 3
     [Documentation] ..
     [Tags]  3
     ..
     ..
```

Here, lets say Test 1 passed and Test 2 failed, then I want Robot to rerun Test 2 , say 2 times, before trying to execute Test 3. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you want without writing your own custom test runner.